# Mailer utlity in java

Tags: java, utilities, mailer

I am using java mailer utility to send mails in my application. When ever there is any  invalid mail id we are getting deliver failure notice. Is there any way to stop that failure notice?

Please help in this.

Comment: Are you not worried by delivery failures ? You're not sending spam, are you ? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change your from-address to `noreply@example.com` (replace example.com with your domain). Also remember to create that address in your mail-server software to make sure email to that mailbox will be discarded.